# Opencv and tensorflow's pbtxt files

Tags: tensorflow, opencv

I'm a newbie in working with opencv and DNN models.
When I walked through some very basic examples, I saw that they need 2 files to read net: config file (pbtxt) and weight file (pb).
I checked tensorflow and just found the way to export pb file (data file) or pbtxt file (text file).
I also saw some articles about how to convert pb to pbtxt in opencv.
My concerns are:

1. When I work with tensorflow, how can I export pbtxt file to feed to opencv? Should I export pb file then use opencv to export pbtxt file?
2. If I can export pbtxt file from pb file, why does opencv need both files?

Answer (score 1):

The `pbtxt` is a text graph representation used by openCV DNN module, but it's not mandatory. It contains the model configuration. It is only required under specific circumstances, for example if you are using a model generated using the Tensorflow Object Detection API, as described [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API).